# How to calculate the surface area of the elliptical paraboloid given by $z=x^2 + 4y^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Also, $z$ should lie in the closed interval of $[0,4]$.

I know the general method to this - to find the function $\langle x, y, z(x,y)\rangle$ differentiated with respect to $x$, then with respect to $y$, finally taking their cross-product and double integrating. However, I would really appreciate a step-by-step solution as not only do I end up with an integral I don't exactly know how to integrate, but I also feel like I am making small errors and would just like to make sure I'm on the right path.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) might be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

$dS = \|(-2x,-8y,1)\|\ dy\ dx\\
\sqrt{4x^2 + 64y^2 + 1} \ dy\ dx$

$\iint \sqrt{4x^2 + 64y^2 + 1} \ dy\ dx$

Limits:  $z=4$

$4 = x^2 + 4y^2$

We can stay in cartesian in which case:

$x = 2\sqrt {1-y^2}\\y=1$

Or, we could flip to an elliptical version of polar coordinates

$x = 2r\cos t\\y = r\sin t\\ dy\ dx = 2r \ dr\ d\theta.$

Up to you.

At $z=0,x,y=0$

Lets stay in cartesian, as I don’t know if you are comfortable with coordinate transformations.

$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\sqrt{1-y^2}} \sqrt{4x^2 + 64y^2 + 1}\ dx \ dy$

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer. However, I apologize if I'm missing something, but shouldn't the magnitude of (-2x, -8y, 1) be the square root of 4x^2 + 64y^2 + 1?

Comment: Oh, you are right!  I will edit back to that place, but I do not have the time right now to work it forward again.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much once again. I've really been stuck.